# why is this showing up?

Tags: jupyter, exploratory

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b7eb239f86a7> in <module>
      1 # Initialize path to SQLite database
      2 path = 'data/classic_rock.db'
----> 3 con = sq3.Connection(path)
      4 
      5 

NameError: name 'sq3' is not defined
```

Comment: Hey Tom, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to add the code that is causing this error output. That will better help us diagnose the proble.

Comment: Are you able to provide more context? Showing the error doesn't give enough information for anyone to offer help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the traceback that you are attempting to use `sq3` and you either did not `import` the library or did not correctly alias the library in question. Cannot know for sure without your code though.

Answer (score 0):

'sq3' is not defined

That's why. Somewhere in your code you're expecting a variable called sql3 but it doesn't exist.